# Create sequence number based on multiple columns

Tags: excel, sequencing

I have an excel spreadsheet where I have

```
City             PN No                                    Accepted Date
bracknell        Each PN is unique i.e BRK-1-PN222        26/7/23  
Ipswich          IPS-1-PN14                               5/12/23  
Sheffield        SHE-1-PN123                              6/12/23
```

I am trying to get it to put a sequence for each city in order of Accepted Date  There are hundreds of rows with multiple cities, PN numbers and dates.  Some Cities have Multiple Accepted Dates which could be the same, but I need it to treat each one as new.

I have sorted data by City and Oldest to Newest Accepted Date, and tried to add a helper column for when the city changes, but it is still not giving me a new sequential number when the city changes

Comment: What formula did you put in the "helper column"?

Comment: Assuming City is in Column A, PN No in Column B, Accepted Date in Column C; and also assuming the titles are in Row 1 and the Data starts in Row 2; Sort the data by City then Accepted Date (Oldest to Newest) and put this formula in Cell $D$2
`=COUNTIF($A$2:A2,A2)`
 Drag the formula down (or double click the fill icon)